# Store a SQLite Table in an ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, sqlite.net

```
public ObservableCollection<AppUser> AppUser { get; set; }

public AppUserDbConnect(string dbPath)
{
    _database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
    _database.CreateTableAsync<AppUser>().Wait();
    this.AppUser = new ObservableCollection<AppUser>(_database.Table<AppUser>());
}
```

This code creates a database connection and then create a table based on the `AppUser` Model.  I'm trying to store the results of the last line but i'm faced with the following error:

> CS1503    Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   `Dialler1.DatabaseConnection.AsyncTableQuery<AppUser>` to
>   `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AppUser>`

Comment: it feels like you are hoping to be informed whenever data gets added to that table. Thats not going to happen

Comment: you're using the async API, so you need to await the result, as well as convert it to a List

Comment: Yeah that's what i'm after @pm100

Comment: So how do i go about it? Do you need to see more of my code to make a more informed decision@pm100

Comment: what are you trying to do. Are you wanting to know when anybody adds data (ie other apps do it) or when your app adds data

Comment: i want to know when my app adds data.

Comment: then you should put code in your write function to announce the change. You are not going to get the sqlite engine to call you when a write happens

Comment: use MessagingCenter or a custom event in your data layer to notify about any new data being inserted

Comment: Thanks  @pm100. Really saved me from going down a rabbithole.

Answer (score 0):

call **ToList** for `db.Table<T>()`

```
 this.AppUser = new ObservableCollection<AppUser>(_database.Table<AppUser>().ToList());
```